# Browser defined and user defined css properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have declared css properties 'right' and 'width' on an division element but the browser sets 'left' property to it automatically. Is there any way to check whether I set 'right' or 'left' property myself in original html document. I am using jQuery.

Comment: Plesse do not hesitate to post your code so that it would be easier?

Comment: can you post your code.?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `css` function. It return value of given css property.

```
<div id="theid" style="right: 10px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cssright = $('#theid').css('right');
var cssleft = $('#theid').css('left');
alert(cssright);     // 10px
alert(cssleft);     // auto
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the property yourself in the original HTML, it will be viewable in the page source. jQuery (or any javascript) can only add the property to the element in the DOM, so it will not be viewable in the source, though it will be viewable in a property inspector like Firebug.

So just view source -- if it's not there in a style property for the tag, but you can see the property in Firebug, it was added in after page-load by JavaScript.